# MySQL Statement to joins 2 tables and sum same items qty

Tags: php, mysql, vs-web-application-project

I have 2 tables, customer and transaction.

```
Customer:
--------------------------------------------
ID | Name            | Tel
--------------------------------------------
1  | Peter           | 123 4567
2  | John            | 456 1234
3  | Alice           | 789 4561
4  | Amy             | 741 8525

Transaction:
--------------------------------------------
CustID | Books | Pens  | Ruler
--------------------------------------------
  1    |   2   |  0    |   1
  2    |   1   |  0    |   0
  1    |   0   |  3    |   0
  1    |   0   |  0    |   1
  2    |   1   |  1    |   1
  3    |   0   |  2    |   2
```

I need the following

```
Results:
-------------------------------------------------------------------
ID | Name          | Tel            | Books | Pens  | Ruler
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | Peter         | 123 4567       |   2   |   3   |   2
2  | John          | 456 1234       |   2   |   1   |   1
3  | Alice         | 789 4561       |   0   |   2   |   2
4  | Amy           | 741 8525       |   0   |   0   |   0
```

Basically it will sum the Books, Pens and Ruler of the same Customer.

I've tried:

```
                        $sql = "select 
                                    `customer`.id,
                                    `custmaster`.name,
                                    `custmaster`.tel,
                                    `transaction`.id,
                                    `transaction`.books,
                                    `transaction`.pens,
                                    `transaction`.ruler,
                                from `customer` 
                                left join `transaction` 
                                on `customer`.id=`transaction`.custid 
                                ORDER BY `customer`.id ASC";
```

But display none. :( I do understand that I needed the sum() function somewhere. Anybody can help?

Answer (score 0):

Use `SUM` and `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, c.tel, SUM(t.books) as books, SUM(t.pens) AS pens, SUM(t.ruler) AS ruler
FROM customer AS c
LEFT JOIN transactions AS t ON c.id = t.custid
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY c.id
```

Comment: Nice... shortcut the table names for easy reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
select 
    `customer`.id,
    `custmaster`.name,
    `custmaster`.tel,
    `transaction`.id,
    sum(`transaction`.books) as books,
    sum(`transaction`.pens) as pens,
    sum(`transaction`.ruler) as ruler,
from `customer` 
left join `transaction` 
on `customer`.id=`transaction`.custid
Group by `customer`.id,`customer`.Name
ORDER BY `customer`.id ASC";
```

Comment: Do I need to have 2 group by? or can I just group by `customer`.id will do. I sort of test both, both give same results.

Comment: No point in selecting `transaction.id`, since you're aggregating all the transactions.

Comment: @SykesTang Strict SQL says that you have to list all the non-aggregated columns in the `GROUP BY` clause. But MySQL allows you to leave them out, so you only need the columns that define the group.